# How to parse CSV in CasperJS with Papa Parse?

Tags: javascript, casperjs, papaparse

I am trying to load and parse a csv file in CasperJS with papa parse.

This is the code for that task

```
var casper = require('casper').create({   
    verbose: true, 
    logLevel: 'debug',
    userAgent: 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.10; rv:34.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/34.0',
    pageSettings: {
        loadImages:  true,
        loadPlugins: false,
        webSecurityEnabled: false     
    },
    clientScript: [
        'jquery-2.1.3.min.js',
        'jquery.csv-0.71.min.js',
        'papaparse.min.js'
        ],

    viewportSize: {
        width: 1440,
        height: 900
    }
});

var fs = require('fs');

casper.on('remote.message', function(msg) {
    this.echo('remote message caught: ' + msg);
});

casper.start();

casper.then(function(){

    var input = fs.read('order4.csv');

    var config = {
        delimiter: "",  // auto-detect
        newline: "",    // auto-detect
        header: true,
        dynamicTyping: false,
        preview: 0,
        encoding: "",
        worker: false,
        comments: false,
        step: undefined,
        complete: undefined,
        error: undefined,
        download: false,
        skipEmptyLines: true,
        chunk: undefined,
        fastMode: undefined
    }

    var a = {'config' : config, 'input' : input}

/*    var result = this.evaluate(function(input) {
            //console.log(input);
            var results = jquery.csv.toObjects(input);
            console.log(results);
            return results;
        },input);*/

    //var result = Papa.parse(a['input'],a['config']);


    var result = this.evaluate(function(a) { 
        console.log('111111111111111111111' + a['input']);
        var results = Papa.parse(a['input'],a['config']);
        console.log('2222222222222222222' + results);

        return results;
    },a);

    this.echo('333333333333333' + result);
});

casper.run();
```

`$input` inside `evaluate` is visible but `$results` is null as well as `$result` in the last command.

Is there a better way load and parse a csv file in CasperJS. How can call `Papa.parse` outside of `evaluate()` since I just want to load a local csv file.

Comment: Like the print_r() in php. Yes I see console.log from inside evaluate. The the console.log inside evaluate are just to check if there is anything happening inside evaluate.

Comment: Its not the whole script. Just that part is not working. I have the function print_r() that is not the problem.

Comment: That would be the whole script at least the part which is not working '11111....' is visible including the input. '222222...' is not visible, not even the string of 2. '333333...' is visible but result === null

Comment: Ok, that means that there is some error with `Papa` in the page context. You can additionally register the `page.error` event to see what error this is. I suspect `Papa` is undefined, because clientScripts are not injected into an empty page. What happens when you use `casper.start('http://example.com')`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that Papa Parse works in the outer context, so you don't need `evaluate` to use it.

Here is a complete script:

```
var fs = require('fs');
eval(fs.read('papaparse.min.js'));

var config = {
    delimiter: "",  // auto-detect
    newline: "",    // auto-detect
    header: true,
    dynamicTyping: false,
    preview: 0,
    encoding: "",
    worker: false,
    comments: false,
    step: undefined,
    complete: undefined,
    error: undefined,
    download: false,
    skipEmptyLines: true,
    chunk: undefined,
    fastMode: undefined
};

console.log(JSON.stringify(Papa.parse(fs.read('order4.csv'), config), undefined, 4));

phantom.exit();
```

Note that `eval` is not evil in this case if you know that papaparse.min.js actually does what it is supposed to do.